# Iptable rules not behaving as expected

Tags: iptables

I have the following iptable rules for a new system.

Basically I am trying to allow incoming www, ssl and ssh and allow outgoing ftp,ssh,smtp,dns,www and ssl connections.  Plus a special rules for an outgoing mysql connection to a specific mysql server, a DoS attack helper and some dropped packet logging.  All other connections I want dropped.

My trouble is, every single time I run the shell script for these rules, I get locked out tighter than a drum.  It drops the established ssh session and won't allow me to begin a new one.  I have to reboot through a console as even flushing the rules in a console session does not help.

It does not matter if the fallback rules (top three after the flush) are at the beginning or the end.  I've tried many ways and I am hoping a new set of eyes may see what I am missing:

```
iptables -F

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dport 21,22,25,53,80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sport 21,22,25,53,80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 172.xxx.xxx.xxx --sport 1024:65535 -d 172.xxx.xxx.xxx --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 172.xxx.xxx.xxx --sport 3306 -d 172.xxx.xxx.xxx --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -m limit --limit 25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT

iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables Packet Dropped: " --log-level 7
iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP
```

Any help would be appreciated.  NOTE: I obfuscated the internal IP for posting.

Comment: serverfault.com could be a more fitting place to ask.

Comment: Well, it took taking a break to note a few things (a couple of missing s on the multiport rules, for instance) but what turned out to be the real culprit was the use of eth0.  The adapter I am connecting through is NOT eth0.  Got rid of all the '-i eth0' and '-o eth0' and this works perfectly.